# get first occurrence of a certain combination of columns

Tags: sql, hive

```
+---------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
|ID_NOTIFICATION|CD_ETAT|TYP_MVT|DT_CAPT            |
+---------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
|3111341        |AT     |C      |2019-06-12 00:03:37|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:08:43|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:10:11|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:10:50|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:11:34|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:12:03|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:14:04|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:14:40|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:15:22|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:15:57|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:25:28|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:25:29|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:27:50|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:28:37|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:32:22|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-12 15:32:59|
|3111341        |EC     |M      |2019-06-12 15:33:04|
|3111341        |AN     |M      |2019-06-13 00:04:33|
|3111341        |TE     |M      |9999-01-01 00:00:00|
+---------------+-------+-------+-------------------+
```

How can I get distinct rows on only certain columns?

I tried:

```
select id_notification, cd_etat, min(dt_capt)
FROM lkr_send_notification
GROUP BY id_notification, cd_etat;
```

But it only returns:

```
+---------------+-------+-------------------+
|ID_NOTIFICATION|CD_ETAT|DT_CAPT            |
+---------------+-------+-------------------+
|3111341        |AN     |2019-06-12 15:08:43|
|3111341        |AT     |2019-06-12 00:03:37|
|3111341        |EC     |2019-06-12 15:33:04|
|3111341        |TE     |9999-01-01 00:00:00|
```

But I also want the result to include:

```
|3111341        |AN     |2019-06-13 00:04:33|
```

Actually I need to get every change that occurs on CD_ETAT.

I asked for the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480938/get-a-row-after-each-time-a-certain-column-changes) but on Spark. I am willing to do it in SQL now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()`:

```
SELECT sn.*
FROM (SELECT sn.*,
             LAG(cd_etat) OVER (PARTITION BY id_notification ORDER BY dt_capt) as prev_cd_etat
      FROM lkr_send_notification sn
     ) sn
WHERE prev_cd_etat IS NULL OR prev_cd_etat <> cd_etat;
```

This returns every row where the state changes.

Comment: Thank you! Just a question: How can I filter the results on ID_NOTIFICATION? I wanted to test with adding and sn.id_notification = '3111341' at the end of the query but it still returns all rows of source

Comment: @AbderrahmenM . . . You should be able to add a `WHERE` clause in either the outer query or inner query.  You just have to use parentheses to be sure the conditions are evaluated correctly.

Comment: Oh I forgot parentheses. Works now. Thanks!